# setup Vscode for debbuging Eigen

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, eigen3

I am using the Eigen library (https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/GettingStarted.html) for some computations.

The program that I am running is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
 
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
 
int main()
{
  MatrixXd m(2,2);
  m(0,0) = 3;
  m(1,0) = 2.5;
  m(0,1) = -1;
  m(1,1) = m(1,0) + m(0,1);
  std::cout << m << std::endl;
}
```

In their documentation by recommend compiling with:

```
g++ -I /path/to/eigen/ my_program.cpp -o my_program
```

If I run this, it compiles and runs... But now I would like to able to debug through the code.

The `.json` files generated I am using are:

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-I",
                "${eigen}",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

**launch.json**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++ - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

and

**c_cpp_properties.json**

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/home/pc/eigen/" 
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++11",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

This configuration just runs the code but does not stick the debugger to it.

Would really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this worked for me:

1º Download Eigen:

```
https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page
```

2º Create a symbolic link to the eigen folder

```
sudo ln -s location/of/Eigen/Folder  /usr/local/include/
```

3º Can compile code with:

```
g++ my_program.cpp -o my_program
```

4º To "better debug" Eigen use the custom python printer for gdb

```
https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/blob/master/debug/gdb/printers.py

a) Create a hidden file called gdbinit 
    touch ~/.gdbinit
b) Place the following code in it:
    python
    import sys
    sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/eigen/printer/directory')  #In my case it was /home/pc/eigen/debug/gdb
    from printers import register_eigen_printers
    register_eigen_printers (None)
    end
```

Note: VScode worked straight out of the box (F5 and debug mode was on!)